# Facing issue in Hive query in generating missing dates

Tags: sql, date, hive, calendar, hiveql

I have a requirement where I need to go back to previous values for a column until 1000 rows and get those previous 1000 dates for my next steps, but all those 1000 previous dates are not present for that column in the table. But I need those missing dates to get from output of the query.

When I try to run below query it is not displaying 1000 previous date values from current date.

Example: let's say only 2 dates are available for date column

```
date      
2019-01-16 
2019-01-19
```

I have come up with a query to get back 1000 dates but it is giving only nearest date as all previous back dates are missing

```
SELECT date FROM  table1 t
WHERE 
date >= date_sub(current_date,1000) and  dt<current_date ORDER BY date LIMIT 1
```

If I run above query it is displaying `2019-01-16`, since previous 1000 days back date are not present it is giving nearest date ,which is `2019-01-16` but I need missing dates starting from `2016-04-23` (1000th date from current date) till before current date (`2019-01-18`) as output of my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate dates for required range in the subquery (see `date_range` subquery in the example below) and `left join` it with your table. If there is no record in your table on some dates, the value will be null, dates will be returned from the `date_range` subquery without gaps. Set `start_date` and `end_date` parameters for date_range required:

```
set hivevar:start_date=2016-04-23; --replace with your start_date
set hivevar:end_date=current_date; --replace with your end_date

set hive.exec.parallel=true;
set hive.auto.convert.join=true; --this enables map-join
set hive.mapjoin.smalltable.filesize=25000000; --size of table to fit in memory

with date_range as 
(--this query generates date range, check it's output
select date_add ('${hivevar:start_date}',s.i) as dt 
  from ( select posexplode(split(space(datediff('${hivevar:end_date}','${hivevar:start_date}')),' ')) as (i,x) ) s
) 

select d.dt as date,
       t.your_col --some value from your table on date
  from date_range d 
       left join table1 t on d.dt=t.date 
order by d.dt --order by dates if necessary
```

Comment: Thank you.Above query might work as we know start date in advance . But in my case start date comes from same table and it changes every day as the job runs . For ex:- 1000 th day from today is 2016-04-23 but in tomorrow's run it might be 2016-04-24 and next days run it might be 2016-04-25 ..we are restricted to use this in one query and no intermediate tables can be created in our customized framewor so finding bit challenge here .

Comment: @user2883028 This is very easy to achieve. Customize parameters, or substitute them directly in the subquery. For example `date_sub(current_date,1000)` instead of `'${hivevar:start_date}'`. Just edit accordingly.

Comment: I could able to make changes and got the output , still it is exploding from 2017-01-02 since in my joining table currency does not have dates beyond that . but still as per your query it should do left outer join and bring all dates starting from 1000th previous date 2016-04-23 till 2019-01-18 .below is the query i tried

Comment: with date_range as 
(--this query generates date range, check it's output
select date_add (date_sub(current_date,1000) ,s.i) as dt 
  from ( select posexplode(split(space(datediff(current_date,date_sub(current_date,1000))),' ')) as (i,x) ) s
)

select d.dt as date1,
       t.perioddt --some value from your table on date
  from date_range d 
       left join currencytable t on d.dt=t.perioddt