# Hive QL to populate a sequence of numbers between limits

Tags: hive, hiveql

Not sure how to put this in a straight forward manner but I'm trying to make something work in Hive SQL. I need to create a sequence of numbers from lower limit to upper limit.

Ex:
`select min(year) from table`

> > Let's assume it results in `2010`

`select max(year) from table`

> > Let's assume it results in `2015`

I need to publish each year from `2010` to `2015` in a select query.

And I'm trying to put the `min` calculation & `max` calculation inside the same SQL which will/should create sequential years in the output.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Well I have an idea but in order to use it, you will have to define the lowest possible and the largest possible values for the years that might be present in your table.

Let's say the smallest possible year is 1900 and the largest possible year is 2200.
Since the largest possible difference in this case is `2200-1900=300`, you will have to use the following string: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 ... ... 298 299 300`.

In the query, you split this string using space as a delimiter thus getting an array, and then you explode that array.
Have a look:

```
SELECT
  minval + delta

FROM
  (
    SELECT
       min(year) minval,
       max(year) maxval,
       split('0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 ... ... ... 298 299 300', ' ') delta_list
    FROM
    table
  ) t
  LATERAL VIEW explode(delta_list) dlist AS delta

WHERE (maxval-minval) >= delta 
;
```

So you end up with 301 rows but you only need the rows with delta values not exceeding the difference between max year and min year, which is reflected in the where clause

Answer (score 2):

```
set hivevar:end_year=2019;
set hivevar:start_year=2010;

select ${hivevar:start_year}+i as year
from
(
select posexplode(split(space((${hivevar:end_year}-${hivevar:start_year})),' ')) as (i,x)
)s;
```

Result:

```
year    

2010    
2011    
2012    
2013    
2014    
2015    
2016    
2017    
2018    
2019
```

Have a look also at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54267593/2700344) answer about generating missing dates.